# path variable won't bind to controller method parameter object property

Tags: spring-mvc

I can't make Spring MVC bind my path variables to my custom object.

Given following controller method:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/customer/{type}/{id}/account/{accountNo}/operation")
  public Mono<Response> getAccountHistory(CustomerData customerData) {
    System.out.println("Customer data: " + customerData);
    return Mono.just(Response.builder().build());
  }
```

DTO class:

```
public class CustomerData {
  private String id;
  private String type;
  private String accountNo;

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public String getAccountNo() {
    return accountNo;
  }

  public void setAccountNo(String accountNo) {
    this.accountNo = accountNo;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "CustomerData{" +
      "id='" + id + '\'' +
      ", type='" + type + '\'' +
      ", accountNo='" + accountNo + '\'' +
      '}';
  }
```

And test snippet

```
client.get().uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
  .path("/customer/{type}/{id}/account/{accountNo}/operation")
  .build("TYPE", "12345678", "11102055610000350203650330")
).accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
  .exchange()
```

I get output

```
Customer data: CustomerData(id=null, type=null, accountNo=null)
```

So no path variable is bound to the object.

However binding to simple types using @PathVariable works like a charm - changing the controller method definition to

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/customer/{type}/{id}/account/{accountNo}/operation")
  public Mono<Response> getAccountHistory(@PathVariable("type") String type, @PathVariable("id") String id,
                                          @PathVariable("accountNo") String accountNo) {

    val customerData = new CustomerData();
    customerData.setAccountNo(accountNo);
    customerData.setType(type);
    customerData.setId(id);

    System.out.println("Customer data: " + customerData);

    return Mono.just(Response.builder().build());
  }
```

Produces the expected output:

```
Customer data: CustomerData{id='12345678', type='TYPE', accountNo='11102055610000350203650330'}
```

What am I doing wrong?

My Controller class is annotated with

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
```

Comment: I am getting same problem and I am using `2.3.2.RELEASE`. Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: No resolution so far, workaround by binding the params manually

Comment: Yeah I was also forced to bind manually and as a side effect `@Valid` annotation had to be removed from method signature.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your code to an empty Spring Boot project and it works fine in the browser when accessing it like so:

```
http://localhost:8080/customer/someType/someId/account/someAccount/operation
```

Your testing snippet, however, looks incomplete/wrong and does not set all parameters.

Comment: Which parameters are not set? And which Spring Boot version you were using? I have performed my test using spring-boot-starter-parent 2.2.4.RELEASE

Answer (score -1):

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/customer/{type}/{id}/account/{accountNo}/operation")
public Mono<Response> getAccountHistory(@PathParam("type") String type, @PathParam("id") String id, @PathParam("account") String account) {
    CustomerData customerData = new CustomerData();
    customerData.setType(type);
    customerData.setId(id);
    customerData.setAccount(account);
    System.out.println("Customer data: " + customerData); return Mono.just(Response.builder().build()); }
```

Comment: How does this refer to the question? You have only modified my snippet